# Use PyCharm interpreter outside of PyCharm terminal

Tags: python, import, pycharm, ide, interpreter

I'm testing some library integration and I wanted to run it outside of PyCharm's terminal. I tried the ordinary `python ./client.py` after moving to the script's directory, but the response says it cannot find my modules. I tried directly calling the interpreter in the project's 'venv' folder `./venv/bin/python ./core/client.py`, but again it tells me it cannot find the module. How can I use this interpreter outside of the PyCharm IDE?

If you need it, the project's file system looks like this:

```
- Sparro
    - core
        - __init__.py
        - client.py
        - packagers.py
        - queue_manager.py
        - server.py
        - utils.py
    - strategy
        - pairs.py
    - venv
        - bin
            - ...
            - python3
        - include
        - python3.8
            - site-packages
```

Comment: You need to activate your environment, so assuming *nix, `source bin/activate`

Answer (score 1):

## Windows

In your pycharm project folder, if you're on windows open a cmd and run the command `.\venv\Scripts\activate`.

## Mac/Linux

If you're on mac/linux open a terminal and run `source venv/bin/activate`.
This will put you in your virtual environment for that project and your scripts will be able to use the modules that you installed.

---

For more info on virtual environments you can check out the documentation [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/).

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue. After activating the venv as aechaechaech suggests, I still got module not found errors for paths that I had added manually to the pycharm interpreter. Turns out that setting `PYTHONPATH` to include them in the activated venv does the trick.

So on Linux activate the Pycharm venv with
`source venv/bin/activate` and then add your custom paths to `PYTHONPATH` with `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/libs`.